# How can I view and print PDFs in Python?

Tags: python, pdf, pyqt

Is there a GPL or less restrictive (preferred LGPL) library to view & print PDFs?

I'm using PyQt, maybe there's a possibility to render PDFs using it?

Comment: You are probably best off using an external renderer/viewer. I base this guess on the fact that nobody embeds ghostscript into their application despite it having been around forever. http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~ghost/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try [python-poppler](http://www.google.com/search?q=python-poppler).  [Poppler](http://poppler.freedesktop.org/) is a well known PDF renderer (used by [Okular](http://okular.kde.org/download.php), among other programs) based on [xpdf](http://xpdf-).  However, this particular binding is fairly new, and doesn't seem to have a real home page.

Comment: GNOME's Evince also uses libpoppler :)

Answer (score 1):

You might want to check out this Qt Quarterly post - [Poppler: Displaying PDF Files with Qt](http://doc.trolltech.com/qq/qq27-poppler.html) that explains how to do this in Qt. It's in C++ but I see poppler has Python bindings so it shouldn't be a problem to port the example code in the post to Python.

Answer (score 0):

Reportlab - http://www.reportlab.com/software/opensource/

Comment: This seems to be intended solely for generating PDFs.